# How to get values with any depth in dict via *args parameter? (python)

Tags: python, dictionary

For example, here I have:

```
doc = { 'A':1, 'B':1, 'C':{'C-A':2, 'C-B':{'C-B-A':3}}
```

then I define a func like this:

```
def get(doc, *args):
    if(len(args) == 1):
        return doc[args[0]]
    if(len(args) == 2):
        return doc[args[0]][args[1]]
    if(len(args) == 3):
        return doc[args[0]][args[1]][args[2]]
```

so I can get values like this:

```
get(doc,'A') //return 1
get(doc,'C','C-A') //return 2
get(doc,'C','C-B') //return {'C-B-A':3}
get(doc,'C','C-B','C-B-A') //return 3
```

**Now my question is, if doc has any depth, how to rewrite func *get*?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [`reduce`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.reduce):

```
In [17]: doc = { 'A':1, 'B':1, 'C':{'C-A':2, 'C-B':{'C-B-A':3}}}
    ...: 
    ...: def get(doc, *args):
    ...:     return reduce(dict.get, args, doc)

In [18]: get(doc, 'A')
Out[18]: 1

In [19]: get(doc, 'C', 'C-A')
Out[19]: 2

In [20]: get(doc, 'C', 'C-B', 'C-B-A')
Out[20]: 3
```

You can think of `reduce` as if it was:

```
def reduce(function, arguments, initializer):
    a = initializer
    for b in arguments:
        a = function(a, b)
    return a
```

I.e. it "accumulates" values calling a binary function over the given arguments.
In your case first `a` is `doc`. Then, it becomes the result of `doc[arguments[0]]`. If `arguments` was length one the iteration stops and the result is returned, otherwise it is one of the sub-dicts and at the next iteration the loop will take a value from that sub-dict.

---

Note that using recursion means limiting to a depth of `sys.getrecursionlimit()`, which usually is about 1000, and it will be *much* slower since you are doing at least two times the function calls to retrieve the value:

```
In [84]: def get(doc, *args):
    ...:     return reduce(dict.get, args, doc)

In [85]: def get2(doc, *args):
    ...:     return get2(doc[args[0]], *args[1:]) if args else doc

In [86]: %timeit get(doc, 'C', 'C-B', 'C-B-A')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 621 ns per loop

In [87]: %timeit get2(doc, 'C', 'C-B', 'C-B-A')
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.04 us per loop

In [88]: d = make_dict(depth=350) 

In [89]: %timeit get(d, *range(350))
10000 loops, best of 3: 38.9 us per loop

In [90]: %timeit get2(d, *range(350))
1000 loops, best of 3: 973 us per loop
```

And this using a shallow dict. If you try with a dict with bigger depths the recursive solution will get slower and slower compared to the functional solution.

Answer (score 2):

Use recursion:

```
def get(doc, *args):
    return get(doc[args[0]], *args[1:]) if args else doc
```

Or, if for whatever reason you prefer doing it iteratively

```
def get(doc, *args):
   for arg in args:
      doc = doc[arg]
   return doc
```

And that's damn near to @Bakuriu's answer.

Comment: Thanks for giving a general solution!